# Non-Homogeneous linear equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can anyone help me solve the general solution to this non homogeneous linear equation:

$x_1'=-ax_2$

$
x_2'=a(x_1)+t $

using fundamental matrix solutions?

Thanks :)

Comment: Where did this problem come from?

Answer (score 1):

We can write this system as:

$$x'(t) = \begin{bmatrix} x'_1(t) \\ x'_2(t)\end{bmatrix}  = A(t) x(t) + f(t).$$

This is known as a non-homogeneous system with a time-varying matrix $A(t)$ and time-varying forcing function $f(t)$.

So, we have:

$$x'(t) = \begin{bmatrix} x'_1(t) \\ x'_2(t)\end{bmatrix}  = A(t) x(t) + f(t) = \begin{bmatrix}0 & -a \\ at & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x_1(t) \\ x_2(t)\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ t\end{bmatrix}.$$

Are you learning to work with these at the moment or does this look vaguely familiar?

In general, these would likely fall under a continuous-time linear system, which has a solution (let $f(t)$ be $B(t)$):

$$\displaystyle x(t) = \boldsymbol \phi(t,t_0)\boldsymbol x(t_0) + \int_{t_0}^t \boldsymbol \phi(t,\tau)\boldsymbol B(\tau)\boldsymbol u(\tau)d\tau$$

**Update**

These are typically very difficult or impossible to solve as you have to understand the qualitative theory of them before attempting to solve them.

For this, see the [*WA*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%27+%3D+-ay%2C+y%27+%3D+a+t+y+) result, which I am surprised about. If you leave the forcing function in there, it becomes much worse. The typical eigenvalue approach typically falls apart on these problems. Sometimes you can use Laplace transforms to solve them, but it helps to have IC's.

At least now, you have some names of these types of equations and can explore them further (theory and solvability).

**Update 2**

Wow, what a huge difference that makes! Okay, now we have:

$$x'(t) = \begin{bmatrix} x'_1(t) \\ x'_2(t)\end{bmatrix}  = A x(t) + f(t) = \begin{bmatrix}0 & -a \\ a & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x_1(t) \\ x_2(t)\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ t\end{bmatrix}.$$

This leads to the following eigenvalues and eigenvectors:

$\lambda_1 = -i a, v_1 = (-i,1)$

$\lambda_2 =  i a, v_2 = (i, 1)$

No time to complete, but you might want to use Laplace transforms on this and that should make it easier, instead of the homogeneous and particular approach.

Regards

Comment: Yes this is very familiar. I understand I need to solve the homogeneous equation then apply the integral for the varying function?

Comment: We're you given any initial conditions? Also, if you are familiar with these, what methods have you learned to solve them?

Comment: There are no initial conditions, the problem only requires a general solution. I am really just confused as to solve the homogeneous equation involving the 'at' term in the matrix. Usually that matrix is a constant coefficient.

Comment: See my update in the answer.

Comment: Okay there was a mistake with the question and I have now been given the above system. Here I know the homogeneous equation involves cosine and sine values with t_0=0. I think I have the correct initial condition, but I keep getting a highly complicated and incorrect result. Any suggestions?

Comment: Great work! This needs more upvotes and a pretty green $\checkmark$ ;-)